# Why is jquery-ui causing a require error with requireJS?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs

I am getting this message: `Uncaught Error: Module name "core" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

I have looked at [How to use jquery ui with requireJS and knockout-sortable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014557/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-requirejs-and-knockout-sortable) and [How do I use jquery ui with requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113172/how-do-i-use-jquery-ui-with-requirejs).

I had a shim like this:

```
// Note that my paths are set so jqueryui points to right place
'jqueryui/core': ['jquery'],
'jqueryui/widget': ['jqueryui/core'],
'jqueryui/position': ['jqueryui/widget'],
'jqueryui/menu': ['jqueryui/position'],
'jqueryui/autocomplete': [
  'jqueryui/core',
  'jqueryui/widget',
  'jqueryui/position',
  'jqueryui/menu'
]
```

I tried taking away the shim because it's supposed to be AMD. I also tried the export of `$` for kicks from the other link. All permutations complain about the line `require('./core')`.

I understand the error because I never required `core` before this point, but I have the shim. But also the shim probably isn't playing nice with the relative portion.

**Update with more info**

My actual markup is like this on load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/requireconfig.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/problemfile.js"></script>
```

The problem file then does:

`require(['jqueryui/autocomplete'], function(f) { ... });`

However the syntax inside `core.js` is `require('./core')`.

Since Bower is dead/dying I am using npm to install the dependencies directly, so I believe jquery-ui assumes that I'd be doing require on the server rather than on client using requirejs. I see the bits about browserify, but that won't apply to me I believe since my app is PHP/JS not node on the backend.

As mentioned in comment below, I don't believe this is a dupe question since it has to deal with jquery-ui package specifically, rather than a wrong require call in my own written code.

Comment: Why don't you create a custom jQuery ui build rather than loading all components this way...

Comment: As of jQuery UI 1.11, all of the library's source files support using AMD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic require in RequireJS, getting "Module name has not been loaded yet for context" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446844/dynamic-require-in-requirejs-getting-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-c)

Comment: @Louis I don't believe this is a duplicate because the `require('./core`)` is within jquery-ui source whereas the other ticket is about the user's own code

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught Error: Module name "core" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

I am not sure if you have loaded it wrong in other places. But according to you error message. It mean you should either call `requrie` with structure of `requireJS` insteand `commonJS` require:

```js
// recommended to avoid confusion with commonJS
requirejs(['./core'],funcion(){
    console.log('core.js is loaded');
});


// alias of requirejs not recommended (can make confusion when reading)
require(['./core'],funcion(){
    console.log('core.js is loaded');
});
```

**P.S.** *if this answer does not help to solved the issue you will need to provide more details (full config, and how you load `core.js`)*